# yii ajax depedent dropdown issue

Tags: php, yii

i am working on ajax dependent dropdown its working fine but one issue is there ,the dropdownn which is dependendent on another dropdown has a prompt ----- "select".but when the parent dropdown is selected the prompt in dependent dropdown disapppears and is filled with the related data,i want that the prompt should be present there and user should select from dropdown.
right now by difault first data is selected

```
   view form code
<div class="row">
php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'quarter'); ?>
 <?php
$options = array(1 => 'First', 2 => 'Second', 3 => 'Third', 4 => 'Fourth');
$curMonth = date("m", time());
$curQuarter = ceil($curMonth/3);
  $qr = array();
 $qr[$curQuarter] = $options[$curQuarter];
 $qr[$curQuarter-1] = $options[$curQuarter-1];
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'quarter', $qr,array(
'prompt' => 'Select a quarter',
ajax' => array(
'type' => 'POST',
'url' => Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('dynamicProjectUserRoles'),
'update' => '#A2fs_role_id'
 )
 )) ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model, 'quarter'); ?>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'role_id'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'role_id', array(),array(
  'prompt' => 'Select a role',
  'ajax' =>array(
  'type' => 'POST',
  'url' => Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('questions'),
   'update' => '#ques'
   ) 
   )); ?>
   <?php echo $form->error($model, 'role_id'); ?>
   </div>
```

// Controller code

```
 public function actionDynamicProjectUserRoles() {
$project_id = $_POST['A2fs']['project_id'];
$quarter = $_POST['A2fs']['quarter'];
$employee = $_POST['A2fs']['employee_id'];
//$this->pr($project_id);
$id = $this->getEmployeeId($employee);
$conditon = $this->getQuarterDate($quarter);
// find roles of partcular employee
$q = "SELECT role_id FROM employee_project_role WHERE employee_id=$id AND project_id = $project_id and $conditon ";
$cmd = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($q);
//$result = $cmd->queryRow();
$role = $cmd->queryAll();
foreach ($role as $r){
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria = array(
'select' => 'role',
'condition' => 'id=:id',
'params' => array(
':id' => $r['role_id']
)
);
$name = Role::model()->find($criteria);
echo CHtml::tag('option',
array(),CHtml::encode($name->role),true);
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont you also render select option in ajax?

Comment: Well if i am able to use CHtml::dropdownlist then i think problem will resolve, but right  now i am not able to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works - it renders the whole element by given ID. Just add

```
echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ''), 'Select a role', true);
```

before

```
foreach ($role as $r){
```

in controller file.